# How to make UIScrollView stop immediately?

Tags: iphone

I just want to scroll only one page then to another.

I set `m_pScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES` and `m_pScrollView.bounces = NO` but when I scroll to the edge of the page it goes out of the page range and then back, likes an inertia effect.

I just want it scoll only one page not more. Can anyone help me?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    m_pScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    m_pScrollView.delegate = self;
    m_pScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768 * 3, 1024);
    m_pScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    m_pScrollView.bounces = NO;
    m_pScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
    m_pScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;


    Myview *myview = [[Myview alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    Myview *myview2 = [[Myview alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(768, 0, 768, 1024)];

    myview2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    Myview *myview3 = [[Myview alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(768 * 2, 0, 768, 1024)];
    myview3.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


    [m_pScrollView addSubview:myview];
    [m_pScrollView addSubview:myview2];
    [m_pScrollView addSubview:myview3];
    [self.view addSubview:m_pScrollView];
}
```

Comment: i think you made some mistakes...

Comment: if now I am in page 1. I want to scroll to page 2. This code can work well. but if your Paddling is very strong. you can see page 3 a littlie, and then back to page 2......

Comment: without seeing your code its hard to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the content size like this

```
m_pScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x,y);
```

For more about this [Create UIScrollview programmatically](http://unconditionalloop.blogspot.com/2011/04/uiscrollview-programmatically.html)